# how to reveal all string padding from txt file in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I making a word game so Ive set all the word in a .txt file, and i've added a show 1st letter button:

Code:

```
if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"reveal"]) {

    UIAlertView *alertuser;
    NSString *prla = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [lst_word objectAtIndex:nCurrentWord]];
    NSString *finished = [[prla substringToIndex:1] stringByPaddingToLength:prla.length withString: @"_" startingAtIndex:0];

    alertuser = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"This is the first letter:" message:finish delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Thanks" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alerta show];
```

How would I make it show and reveal all the letters from the word in the .txt file?

```
NSString *finishText = [[prlt substringToIndex:1] stringByPaddingToLength:prlt.length withString: @"_" startingAtIndex:0];

    alerta = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"First Letter is:" message:finishText delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Thanks" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alerta show];
```

I need this reversed to allow the full answer from the txt file!

Answer (score 0):

`substringWithRange:` may be the function you are looking for.

The sample code below will print word by word of a string

```
NSString *sampleString = @"abcedefgh";

for(int i = 0; i < [sampleString length]; i++)
{
  NSLog(@"word = %@", [sampleString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)])
}
```

EDIT:

In place of

```
NSString *finishedText = [[prlt substringToIndex:1] stringByPaddingToLength:prlt.length withString: @"_" startingAtIndex:0];
```

use below code, this will solve your issue

```
NSString *finishedText= [prlt substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, prla.length)];
```

Comment: Right now its only revealing one letter of the word from the answers in the .txt file, But I need it to reveal the full word! How does the code you supplied do that?

Comment: I am not sure of your correct requirement. But this will give you full word. [sampleString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, [sampleString length])]

Comment: I want it to fill the whole word in straight from the txt file!

Comment: NSString *finishedText = [[prlt substringToIndex:1] stringByPaddingToLength:prlt.length withString: @"_" startingAtIndex:0];
        
        alerta = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"First Letter is:" message:finishedText delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Thanks" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alerta show];

Comment: try replacing [prlt substringToIndex:1] by [prlt substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, prla.length)]

Comment: NSString *finishedText= [prlt substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, prla.length)];

Comment: yes that Worked! make it code so I can grant it as answer!